# VS code adds margin to editor groups

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: VS code editor margins]

As you can see in the image VS code started to add margins to editor group. When I try to pull it to sides this is the biggest space that I can get.

Update: When I open files side by side still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved when I created a new workspace and add the same folder by using "File->Add Folder to Workspace..."

Answer (score 3):

The selected answer is not the right answer.  I got rid of the margins through View.. Appearance.. [turn off 'Centered Layout']

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

1. press `F1`
2. type "Preferences: Open Settings (UI)"
3. click `Window`
4. under `New Window Dimensions` click `default` or other options.

I don't really know if this helps.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't help.